# NSSplitView crash when delegate assigned

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssplitview

I have a `NSSplitView` inside a `NSViewController's` xib file. If I connect the delegate outlet to File's Owner, or if I do the same thing in code (`self.splitView.delegate = self`) then the app crashes. No error message, it just stops in `main.m`. I have not implemented any of the `NSSplitViewDelegate` methods, just connected the outlet. Here's the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x6f27f8, 0x00007fff8f58a097 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8f58a097 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8dfb98d8 AppKit`-[NSSplitView _effectiveFrameForDrawnFrame:ofDividerAtIndex:] + 477
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8dfb9499 AppKit`-[NSSplitView resetCursorRects] + 500
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8df62664 AppKit`-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 610
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8df62a17 AppKit`-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1557
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8df62a17 AppKit`-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1557
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8df62a17 AppKit`-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1557
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8df62a17 AppKit`-[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1557
    frame #8: 0x00007fff8dfb8f34 AppKit`_handleInvalidCursorRectsNote + 994
    frame #9: 0x00007fff8e5968a1 AppKit`__35-[NSWindow _postInvalidCursorRects]_block_invoke2988 + 46
    frame #10: 0x00007fff81f7de17 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    frame #11: 0x00007fff81f7dd87 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    frame #12: 0x00007fff81f6f468 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 776
    frame #13: 0x00007fff81f6ef25 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    frame #14: 0x00007fff87070a0d HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    frame #15: 0x00007fff87070685 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
    frame #16: 0x00007fff870705bc HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    frame #17: 0x00007fff8de1c3de AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1434
    frame #18: 0x00007fff8de1ba2b AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    frame #19: 0x00007fff8de0fb2c AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 553
    frame #20: 0x00007fff8ddfa913 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 940
```

I have another split view in the app, although it's in a NSWindowController, not view controller. It works fine with the delegate connection. The problematic split view controller is inside one of the window controller's split view panes, if that matters. I should be able to nest them, right?

Comment: Seems like something is getting released. Do you have a strong reference to each of your views?

Comment: It was the view controller itself. I forgot that I was assigning its view to the parent splitview (which would retain the view), but not hanging onto the vc as well. Thanks!